# Setting virtualenv and running python code on boot

Tags: linux, boot, python, cron, virtualenv

I'm trying to have some code executed on boot and haven't been able to get it to run as rc.local, cron, or a system service. So I'm sure I'm doing something wrong -- I just don't know what.

These are the bash commands I type, but would like instead to run on boot...

First - I start a virtualenv that includes Tensorflow

`source ~/tf2/bin/activate`

Then - I run my python code. (There are some funny args to sudo, but I'm running with a specialized LED display that requires them.)

`sudo -HE env PATH=$PATH PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH python3 /home/david/mycode.py`

I think that the virtualenv never gets set, and so the python code can't run, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions of ways to get this running would be appreciated.  (I'm running Raspian on a Raspberry Pi.)

david,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a typo in my /etc/rc.local -- and so I solved this myself.

Answer (score 0):

At boot, `rc.local` runs as `root`. There is no need to use `sudo`. In general, `sudo` does things with your environment, especially with `PATH`. Although the solution was in a typo (as you said yourself), you should refrain from (ab)using `sudo` in the context of `rc.local`.